# Object release behavior in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, object

If I release mainPath in following example the program gives an error (because I’m releasing an object with zero counter)

```
NSString  *mainPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/downloadFile.plist",NSHomeDirectory()];
NSLog(@"address is = %@",mainPath);
[mainPath release]; //Program failed here
```

But the following code works fine.

```
NSString *aa=@"hiiiii";
[aa release];
```

Can anyone explain this?

Actually I’m not clear about the pointer concept (give a suitable link to clear it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constant NSStrings are a special case.  They are allocated statically at compile time and can't be deallocated.  You can send release to a constant string as many times as you like, it'll never get deallocated.  This is achieved in the current implementation by setting the retain count to INT_MAX which is treated as a special value meaning "don't decrement me on release".

Answer (score 3):

You should read the [Cocoa Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) or at least the [Objective-C Tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) by Scott Stevenson. (Really. Do it, you’ll save a lot of time in the long run.) The difference is that the first string is autoreleased, you do not own it and should not release it. The second string is special, I think it’s not allocated on the heap at all and the `release` is essentially a no-op here.

Comment: The second string is statically allocated as part of the program binary, therefore reference counting does not apply to it and retain/release operations will be no-ops.

Answer (score 2):

String with format is a convenience method that autoreleases the string so in this case you are likely to be sending a release message to an already deallocated object.

In your second example, you are creating the string statically so retain counts don't apply.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to release your objects in either of those cases.

As a rule of thumb, if you didn't use `init` (or `initWithFoo:`) to create the object, and didn't deliberately use `retain` to retain the object (plus couple of other rarer cases), you don't need to use `release`.

Comment: that's not correct - the 'key' words when you need to release are alloc, copy and new

Comment: @grahamparks--Consider following case(it has  memory leak)

NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"hello"];        
str=[self getData]; //memory Leak    
[str release];
here hetData is a method that returns an NSString

Comment: @Online-- in your sample there are two potential problems: The 1st string is leaked when you overwrite the pointer to it in the second sentence. And then 'getData' method should return an autoreleased NSString, so that the [str release] is not correct.

Comment: @ tato ---actually i was commenting to  grahamparks answer that there are other ways which can inc or dec retain counter(here if return type is not autorelease)....UPTO MY KNOWLEDGE